# How can submitted values be translatable?

Tags: 8, webforms

Like for the node, we can add the translations and the same node ID can hold all language translations. In a similar fashion, is it possible in Drupal 8 webform?

Comment: Translating webform submissions? Or webforms? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you maybe edit your questions and add some more context, or something like a user story?

Answer (score 3):

Webforms are configuration entities and they need to be translated using a different UI/UX.
@see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfG37uW5Qu8